# scrollpath.js hiding content

Tags: jquery, scroll

I've posted about another issue just before, but since I'm not getting answers, I figured I'd ask a question about a different issue I'm having:

I'm trying to use the jQuery plugin: ScrollPath. I thought it would be fun and interesting to make my page more interactive (it's going to be a portfolio page.) Anyways, I've got the scrolling and everything working in the desired path that I created, but I'm having a problem with how it looks once the browser screen starts to get too small.

On my 13" macbook pro, the site looks wonderful and doesn't cut anything out. On screens larger than mine, it reveals more content, but still looks good.

On lower resolutions than my macbook and/or smaller screens, things start to get cut out of view because of the way the plugin "move(s)To" and focuses on the object being scrolled to.

This is the demo site for the plugin: http://joelb.me/scrollpath/

Here's how the site looks on a responsive test for phones/tablets/etc: http://res.ponsive.com/?resize=joelb.me%2Fscrollpath%2F&iphone=on&ipad=on&android=on

As you can see, the plugin seems to be limiting your ability to see the content.

I'd post an example of the website I'm creating with this plugin, but I would rather not show everyone my stuff just yet. I think by posting the two examples above gets my point across though.

Is there any way to work around this problem? 
Is there a better plugin or method of achieving this fun scrolling path effect without losing the ability to see content on smaller viewports?

Thanks if you can help! (I hope I didn't ramble too much.)

Comment: er... don't use the plugin on smaller screens?

Comment: Thanks Hogan. That will certainly have to be the last resort. I'm just wondering if there is a way to have the plugin work well on smaller screens.